# python regex txt

Tags: python, regex

I have a 1.txt:

```
I. Introduction to Text Mining 1
I.1 Defining Text Mining 1
I.2 General Architecture of Text Mining Systems 13

II. Core Text Mining Operations 19
II.1 Core Text Mining Operations 19
II.2 Using Background Knowledge for Text Mining 41
II.3 Text Mining Query Languages 51

III. Text Mining Preprocessing Techniques 57
III.1 Task-Oriented Approaches 58
III.2 Further Reading 62

IV. Categorization 64
IV.1 Applications of Text Categorization 65
IV.2 Definition of the Problem 66
IV.3 Document Representation 68
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
I. Introduction to Text Mining 1.1
    I.1 Defining Text Mining 1.1
    I.2 General Architecture of Text Mining Systems 13.1

II. Core Text Mining Operations 19.1
    II.1 Core Text Mining Operations 19.1
    II.2 Using Background Knowledge for Text Mining 41.1
    II.3 Text Mining Query Languages 51.1
...
```

two changes:

```
1. I I.1 use the TAB.
2. all number in the end plus 0.1
```

I try use pandas but it isn't work. I try other way,but I don't know how to write the next program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

f=open("D:/Downloads/1.txt")
page_list = []
content=[]
for line in f:
    if re.search('(\d+)$',line) !=None:
        page_list.append(re.search('(\d+)$',line).group())
    if re.search('^(.*\.\d+)',line) !=None:
        content.append(re.search('^(.*\.\d+)',line).group())
str=map(lambda x:x+'.1',page_list)
print str
con=map(lambda x:'\t'+x,content)
print con
```

the result of the program :

```
['1.1', '1.1', '13.1', '19.1', '19.1', '41.1', '51.1']
['\tI.1', '\tI.2', '\tII.1', '\tII.2', '\tII.3']
```

Comment: If you give some time then I will code it for you. Can you please paste your entire input file or give upper limit of your roman numbers?

Comment: @Shiv yes. I have changed the code ,the first code is 1.txt. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(.*)(\d+)
```

And replace by:

```
\1\2.1
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/apIT0O/6)

Sample Code:

```
import re

regex = r"(.*)(\d+)"

test_str = ("I. Introduction to Text Mining 1\n"
    "I.1 Defining Text Mining 1\n"
    "I.2 General Architecture of Text Mining Systems 13\n\n"
    "II. Core Text Mining Operations 19\n"
    "II.1 Core Text Mining Operations 19\n"
    "II.2 Using Background Knowledge for Text Mining 41\n"
    "II.3 Text Mining Query Languages 51\n\n"
    "III. Text Mining Preprocessing Techniques 57\n"
    "III.1 Task-Oriented Approaches 58\n"
    "III.2 Further Reading 62\n\n"
    "IV. Categorization 64\n"
    "IV.1 Applications of Text Categorization 65\n"
    "IV.2 Definition of the Problem 66\n"
    "IV.3 Document Representation 68\n\n")

subst = "\\1\\2.1"


result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Sample Output:

```
I. Introduction to Text Mining 1.1
I.1 Defining Text Mining 1.1
I.2 General Architecture of Text Mining Systems 13.1

II. Core Text Mining Operations 19.1
II.1 Core Text Mining Operations 19.1
II.2 Using Background Knowledge for Text Mining 41.1
II.3 Text Mining Query Languages 51.1

III. Text Mining Preprocessing Techniques 57.1
III.1 Task-Oriented Approaches 58.1
III.2 Further Reading 62.1

IV. Categorization 64.1
IV.1 Applications of Text Categorization 65.1
IV.2 Definition of the Problem 66.1
IV.3 Document Representation 68.1
```

Comment: What should I do for the TAB indent of beginning of  I.1 I.2 III.1 III.2 .....IV.3

Comment: plz look at your sample output, and modify that if change requires

Answer (score 0):

For `TAB` indent you can use this code:

```
for m in re.finditer(r'[IVX]+\.\d.*\n',result):
  oldgroup = m.group()
  newgroup = '\t' + oldgroup
  result = re.sub(oldgroup,newgroup,result)
```